# how to insert new line in insert query in oracle 11g sql

Tags: oracle11g

i want to insert new line between these two line in db."Asperger's syndrome have difficulty with social interaction and communication.They also have a narrow range of interests." i want my o/p to be like this

> 'Asperger's syndrome have difficulty with social interaction and
> communication.
> They also have a narrow range of interests.'

```
insert into ab(column) values ('a'+char(10)+'b');
```

i tried to insert like this but sql shows error

> Error report -
>
> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
> *Cause:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator for string concatenation in Oracle is `||` and the function name is `CHR` instead of `CHAR`.

```
insert into ab(column) values ('a' || chr(10) || 'b');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    insert into ab
  (col1)
values
  (q'[Asperger's syndrome have difficulty with social interaction and communication.]' ||
   chr(13) || 'They also have a narrow range of interests.')
```

Use the above code for your requirement.